# Can I eagerly persist my Ehcache?

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

From the document, I saw:

> Ehcache 3 only offers persistence in the case of clean shutdowns
>   (close() was called). If the JVM crashes there is no data integrity
>   guarantee. At restart, Ehcache will detect that the CacheManager
>   wasn’t cleanly closed and will wipe the disk storage before using it.

Does it mean there's no way I can eagerly flush entries (or some entries I know updated for sure) to disk?

Also, I'd like to know where the close() hooked? Will it be triggered if I manually kill the jvm?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't. But you could add a shutdown hook yourself. However, it works with memory mapped files and in case of a crash, you never know the state of a currently written entry.

Support a clean save is actually an enterprise feature. It is called fast restore.

Note that Ehcache isn't a store, it's a cache. So, fast restore is used to quickly load a cache after a crash. No to save data.